# Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MongoDB.list (Suite)

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-17.10

I was trying to install MongoDb on Ubuntu 17.10 but i couldnt or there were some errors so I decided uninstall everything and reinstall fresh. So i did some purge commands that i found on the net and after doing that now if I do: sudo apt update

i get the following messages

> sudo apt update
>
> E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MongoDB.list
>   (Suite)
>
> E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
>   (Suite)
>
> E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: i used the following command to delete mongodb >sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*

Comment: Getting $ sudo apt-get purge mongodb-enterprise
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-enterprise.list (URI)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-enterprise.list (URI)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, as you dont have a specific line wrong in the file, better delete the file `MongoDB.list` and add again the respective PPA.

Try:

```bash
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MongoDb.list
```

Add again the PPA from MongoDb. Now is time to update by running.

```bash
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running following command

```
sudo sed -i -e '1d' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
```

This would produce following error

```
E: Type '“deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Now to fix this, go to /etc/apt/sources.list.d and then open it with

```
nano mongodb-org-3.4.list
```

And here remove the double quotes (")

Try running sudo apt-get update now. Hopefully it will work.